# Enumeration indicator for number of arguments of a function

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathtools

I'm trying to replicate this style of indicator for dotted enumeration as suggested below[image]

Can some one help me with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a possible MWE for your question modificated thank to the suggestion of @Henri Menke's comment for `\dotsb`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[t\colon \underbrace{V\times V\times\dotsb\times V}_{k+1\text{-times}}\rightarrow V\]
\end{document}
```

After if you prefer to have the same characters of the picture, you can use a clone of Times (New Roman) that is the [newtx](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package (`newtxtext` + `newtxmath`).

This is a screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[t\colon \underbrace{V\times V\times\dotsb\times V}_{k+1\text{-times}}\rightarrow V\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `amsmath` documentation suggests to use `\dotsb` for “dots with binary operators/relations”, i.e. `V \times \dotsb \times V`.